# Auto logout off after PayPal transection

Tags: php, wordpress, function, paypal

I have faced a problem in WooCommerce PayPal transection. I have created a function which is need to run after successfully payment. My function is working on stripe but not working on the PayPal. After order complete I need to know current user email, id and order custom meta, but after every PayPal transection it's redirecting to PayPal  site and when we back on the site thank you page after PayPal payment process, then user will be auto logout. So I can't get the user email, id and etc. I have also tried this by WordPress session but after PayPal payment session also not working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'so_payment_complete' );
function so_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    if ( ! $order_id )
    return;

    $user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    $get_id =  $current_user->ID;
    if ( $order->has_status('completed') ) {

                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
                    if ($product_id == 288522) {


                        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

                            $item1 = $item->get_meta('Retake Course Item');
                        
                            $all_items =array($item1);

                            foreach ($all_items as $course_id) {

                                //My funtions 

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi kane, thanks for posting this snippet, however judging by your description by the time this code is accessed, if it even is, the issue has already happened. It's likely the Paypal redirect is overwriting a session cookie used by WP or something similar. Do you have a WP setting that's something like "log out after a short period of inactivity" or something like that?

Comment: Are you using the latest PayPal Checkout plugin? https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/ -- it has smart payment button integrations that don't redirect away to PayPal and instead use a minibrowser, which should resolve this